# Iframe Scrollbar css

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I go about changing the `css` of an `iframe` scrollbar?

My problem with the current scrollbar in my iframe is the frame is not very wide and the scrollbar appears bulky in it and takes up too much space.

Using `"scrolling="no"` makes the scrollbar disappear but then the user cannot scroll.

By the way, My browser is Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the css to change the scrollbars in iframes in chrome

```
body   {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
html {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: none; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment  {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
   -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: It would be worth mentioning that this css/html should be on the page inside the iframe not the page hosting the iframe right? That how I got it working any way...

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by getting scrollbar element in the frame, for example use jquery:

```
$("#iFrameId").contents().find("-webkit-scrollbar").css("width","5px")
```

But as others said - it's not a pretty solution.

Comment: In `<script>` tags somwhere on your top page. Also remember to reference jquery library...

Answer (score -1):

You can't style a scrollbar (other then to turn it on and off) with CSS at all.

There is some proprietary stuff which lets you apply some styling, but this is supported only by IE and Opera.

<del>Chrome provides no mechanism to do this.</del>

As a commenter points out, WebKit now supports [a different proprietary mechanism for styling scrollbars](http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/). I've no idea if the Chrome build of WebKit has this merged or enabled though.

You *could* look at replacing the scrollbar wholesale with JavaScript, and [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) appears to do a reasonable job of not breaking the usual interaction rules.

That said, changing the appearance of user controls is something I'd try to avoid, and making something users need to aim a pointer at *smaller* sets off the flashing red light marked "[Fitts's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law)".

A better solution would probably be to "Not cram so much information into so little space".

Comment: Thats not entirely true: http://ajaxian.com/archives/webkit-now-lets-you-style-scrollbars

Comment: Could i make a div instead of an iframe and style the div scrollbars?

Comment: — The element chosen makes no difference.