# change iframe scroll bar style

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

Is there any way to change the style of an iframe scroll bar?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use a plugin that will let you do that, such as the following.
http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

just so you know you cant do it with css: [Iframe Scrollbar css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559952/iframe-scrollbar-css)

You can change it with css in IE apparantly.
[Change style scrollbar div for my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645316/change-style-scrollbar-div-for-my-site)

Answer (score 2):

You can also change it from chrome/safari..  (webkit based browsers)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

See [this article](http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) on the webkit blogs. And, [the tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) from where the above snippet was blatantly copied.

For, Mozilla Firefox and family, there's nothing yet. See this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox).