# How to change scroll bar properties to a inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm using the following code to change the main scroll bar properties. But I just only need to change the scroll bar properties of an inside iframe in a page. How am I suppose to do that only?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #ffffff;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #ea421e;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1ex;
}
```

Comment: I hope you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682411/change-iframe-scroll-bar-style

Comment: looks closely same. :)

Comment: I just need to have the same as you can see on the homepage of fb where the online friend list is shown.

Comment: ahh they are using javascript for it...Here's the plugin http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Facebook-like-jQuery-Scrollbar-Plugin-slimScroll/examples/ facebook look like